# Strange behavior of touchmove event in default android browser(called Internet)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, touch, drag

[This drag demo](http://sewa.se/drag/)

If i use chrome android browser all work fine, but if i use default android browser (Internet), then while dragging nothing happens, but after touchend event, dragged item is on the new position. Not showing changes during the touchmove event.

```
$.fn.draggable = function() {
  var offset = null;
  var start = function(e) {
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    var pos = $(this).position();
    offset = {
      x: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - pos.left,
      y: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - pos.top
    };
  };
  var moveMe = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var orig = e.originalEvent;
    $(this).css({
      top: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - offset.y,
      left: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - offset.x
    });
  };
  this.bind("touchstart", start);
  this.bind("touchmove", moveMe);
};

$(".draggable").draggable()
```

I want, that in default android browser drag worked as well in chrome.

Comment: This's problem has been resolved in last version on android. (version 4.2.2). After upgrading to the last version the drag and drop work fine in default android browser.